# Converting a string into Unsigned int 8 array

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash and I am trying to convert a [swift obfuscation](https://gist.github.com/DejanEnspyra/80e259e3c9adf5e46632631b49cd1007) into a bash script.

Basically, I want to convert a string into an Unsigned-Int 8 array (UTF-8).

For example,

```
"hey" = [104, 101, 121] (UTF-8 UINT8 value)
"example" = [101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101] (UTF-8 UINT8 value)
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: In bash there is only text and only type is string. There is no "Unsigned-Int 8 array". Can you explain what _text_ do you want to convert into what _text_ format? You want to convert `hey` into text that starts with `[`, then has comma and space separated bytes in base 10 of UTF-8 encoding of that text, followed by a closing `]`?

Comment: How do you plan to model an uint8 in bash?

Comment: @KamulCuk Thanks for the clarification. UINT8 would mean numbers from 0 to 255. As for the format, it doesn't really matter as long as it is separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shell script converts input in the for of `hey` into the string `[104, 101, 121]`.

```
# Print hey
printf "%s" hey |
# convert to hex one per line
xxd -p -c 1 |
# convert to decimal one per line
xargs -I{} printf "%d\n" 0x{} |
# Join lines with comma
paste -sd, |
# Add spaces after comma
sed 's/,/, /g' |
# Add [ ]
{ echo -n '['; tr -d '\n'; echo ']'; }
# echo "[$(cat)]"
```

The script is not aware of input encoding - the script only translates bytes representation. The input string has to be already in the desired encoding. Use `iconv` to convert between encodings.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get back home.

Comment: I got an error for `paste` arguments, I think for mac users. This answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure bash, no external programs:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

to_codepoints() {
    local LC_CTYPE=C IFS=, n
    local -a cps
    # Iterate over each byte of the argument and append its numeric value to an array                                                                                                                                                            
    for (( n = 0; n < ${#1}; n++ )); do
        cps+=( $(printf "%d" "'${1:n:1}") )
    done
    printf "[%s]\n" "${cps[*]}"
}

to_codepoints hey
to_codepoints example
to_codepoints $'\u00C4ccent'
```

outputs

```
[104,101,121]
[101,120,97,109,112,108,101]
[195,132,99,99,101,110,116]
```